# how to remove a file from file upload control before uploading it using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

I am using a multi-file upload control to upload files.
I am listing the files before I upload so users can see the names of file what are they uploading.
I have a delete button in each file name row.
I am trying to remove the file from the list when I click the remove button, just in case I changed my before I upload.
I am running out of ideas on

```js
              
              var fileInput = document.getElementById('inputfile');
              var fileListDisplay = document.getElementById('allfiles');
              
              var fileList = [];
              var renderFileList, sendFile;
              
              fileInput.addEventListener('change', function (evnt) {
                    fileList = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < fileInput.files.length; i++) {
                    fileList.push(fileInput.files[i]);
                }
                renderFileList();
              });
              
              renderFileList = function () {
                fileListDisplay.innerHTML = '';
                fileList.forEach(function (file, index) {
                    var fileDisplayEl = document.createElement('p');
                  fileDisplayEl.innerHTML = file.name +"<div class=deletfile></div>";
                  fileListDisplay.appendChild(fileDisplayEl);
                });
              };  
            
            
            $(document).on('click','.deletfile', function()
             {  
              var filen=($(this).parent().text());
               console.log(fileList);
              
              const index = fileList.indexOf(filen);
              console.log(index,filen);
                if (index > -1) {
                  fileList.splice(index,1);
                }
                
                //console.log(fileList);
             });
```

```html
<input id="inputfile" type="file" multiple> <br><div id='allfiles'></div>
```

how to do it?

here is my code

delete file function is where I am trying to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, I can see that you forget to remove the dom that why the file still exists.

Another, to make the code simple we can attach `data-index` inside the delete button to remember the file index when we're deleting it will be easy than compare the string of filename.

Here is the modified code.

```js
var fileInput = document.getElementById('inputfile');
var fileListDisplay = document.getElementById('allfiles');

var fileList = [];
var renderFileList, sendFile;

fileInput.addEventListener('change', function (evnt) {
  fileList = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < fileInput.files.length; i++) {
    fileList.push(fileInput.files[i]);
  }
  renderFileList();
});

renderFileList = function () {
  fileListDisplay.innerHTML = '';
  fileList.forEach(function (file, index) {
    var fileDisplayEl = document.createElement('p');
    fileDisplayEl.innerHTML = `${file.name} <button data-index="${index}" class='deletfile'>X</button>`;
    fileListDisplay.appendChild(fileDisplayEl);
  });
};


$(document).on('click','.deletfile', function()
{
  const index= $(this).attr('data-index');
  fileList.splice(parseInt(index, 10), 1);
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```